# How can I expand one axis to 2 axes in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, matlab

Let's say I have a string `ndarray` with any dimension. For example: `[["abc", "def"], ["ghi", "jkl"]]`. Now, I want to split each string into separate chars, such that basically an axis in the second dimension is added: `[[['a', 'd'], ['b', 'e'], ['c', 'f']], [['g', 'j'], ['h', 'k'], ['i', 'l']]]`. Or better said, it should behave like MATLAB converting a string array to a char array:

```
A = 
  2×2 string array
    "abc"    "def"
    "ghi"    "jkl"
```

should become:

```
  2×3×2 char array
ans(:,:,1) =
    'abc'
    'ghi'
ans(:,:,2) =
    'def'
    'jkl'
```

I tried functions like `np.frompyfunc`, `np.apply_over_axis` and `np.apply_from_axis` but so far nothing worked for me. Is there a clever trick to do this?

The reverse is actually pretty simple:

```
def row_to_string(row):
    return ''.join([chr(int(x)) for x in row])

return np.apply_along_axis(row_to_string, 1, np.asarray(x))
```

EDIT: For a 3D example, see this gist: https://gist.github.com/PeterTillema/215f0a6474849a06001e10804e5a6eca

Comment: Just a heads up, `str.join()` accepts a generator as an argument, no need to waste memory creating an interim `list`; `"".join(chr(int(x)) for x in row)`

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is just an iterator; nothing magical about it, especially when working with 2d arrays.  What function where trying to use with apply etc.  What does `frompyfunc(list,1,1)` do for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [159]: alist = [["abc", "def"], ["ghi", "jkl"]]
In [160]: np.frompyfunc(list,1,1)(alist)
Out[160]: 
array([[list(['a', 'b', 'c']), list(['d', 'e', 'f'])],
       [list(['g', 'h', 'i']), list(['j', 'k', 'l'])]], dtype=object)
In [161]: np.array(np.frompyfunc(list,1,1)(alist).tolist())
Out[161]: 
array([[['a', 'b', 'c'],
        ['d', 'e', 'f']],

       [['g', 'h', 'i'],
        ['j', 'k', 'l']]], dtype='<U1')
```

From there you can transpose to the desired layout.

Splitting a string into characters is a python task.  Numpy doesn't have special string code, just `np.char` functions that apply string methods to elements of an string dtype array.

`frompyfunc` is a convenience tool for applying a python function to elements of an array.  It doesn't compile anything, but usually is comparable to list comprehensions in speed, and may be more convenient.

Comment: This works kind of, at least for more dimensions. But I guess something is swapped, see this gist: https://gist.github.com/PeterTillema/215f0a6474849a06001e10804e5a6eca. I tried swapping axis 1 and -1, based on the shape, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Update, I think I fixed it: I had to _move_ the last axis to axis 1, not swap them ;)